# How to Access a Value from a Builder using Custom Operation in a Computation Expression

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I have a Computational Expression Builder which receives
a value during construction

```
type SomeBuilder<'e> (e: 'e) =
    member this.Bind(x, fn) = ...
    member this.Return x  = ...
    member this.ReturnFrom x = ...

let buildSome v = SomeBuilder(v)

buildSome 2 {
    return 1
}
```

Now I'd like to access the value `e` from within the 
Computational Expression via a custom operation so that

```
buildSome 2 {
    return 1 + e()
}
```

So I really want to access properties/values in the underlying builder object and work with them

I imagine I would need something like

```
type SomeBuilder<'e> (e: 'e) =
    member this.Bind(x, fn) = ...
    member this.Return x  = ...
    member this.ReturnFrom x = ...
    [<CustomOperation("e")>]
    member this.E () = e
```

but that doesn't work.

So my question is

a) is something like this possible using CustomOperations and Computational Expressions
b) and if it is possible, how?

**Disclaimer:**
As usual in programming there is a million ways to achieve similar effects
in completely different ways. I am explicitly asking for this particular way
and I am OK if the answer is simply "No". But please refrain from answers that are non answers in the narrowest sense laid out here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll like my answer and whether it's within your boundaries, but you could capture the builder instance using a trick like this:

```
type SomeBuilder<'e> (e: 'e) =
    member this.Value = e

    [<CustomOperation("extract", MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind = true, AllowIntoPattern = true)>]
    member this.Extract (state) = this

    member this.Bind(x, fn) = fn x
    member this.Return x  = x
    member this.ReturnFrom x = x


let builder e = new SomeBuilder<_>(e)

let x = builder 1 {
    extract into builder // now we've brought builder in the scope
    printfn "here we can read the value = %d" builder.Value
    return 0
}
```

Comment: These particular arguments to the `CustomOperationAttribute` will allow access to the parameter of the computation builder too, no need to go via self-identifier and an additional property.

Comment: Hey, what is the `into` thing?

Comment: Also could you explain why the custom operation is needed to bring the builder itself into the scope?

Comment: @kaefer could you elaborate? I don't see how you'd get access to the builder parameters. Maybe by providing a sample?

Comment: @robkuz The `into`thing was introduced in order to do the `query` computation expression ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions)) which looks like the LINQ syntax from C#. The `into` keyword is used for things such `groupBy student.Age into g`. It allows you to bind the return value of the fonction to a name, so in that case I'm bending it to capture the builder itself...

Answer (score 3):

To show that primary constructor arguments are in scope for the builder's instance methods:

```
type SomeBuilder<'e> (e: 'e) =
    member __.Bind(x, fn) = fn x
    member __.Return x = x
    [<CustomOperation("e", MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind = true,  AllowIntoPattern = true)>]
    member __.E _ = e

SomeBuilder 2 {
    e into i
    return 1 + i }
// val it : int = 3
SomeBuilder "bar" {
    e into s
    return "foo" + s }
// val it : string = "foobar"
```

Consider the position of the custom operation inside the builder; it will ignore expressions that precede it.